# Populate combo box visual basic

Tags: vb.net

How to change the text if I select the data in the combobox. Heres the picture of my ongoing system.

I would like when I click the Designation, the salary label will be change depends on the salary stored in my database

[image]

Comment: In future, please post your code as formatted text. Add an image as well if it provides some value but never post a picture without text.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly create the command. Just pass the query and the connection to the data adapter constructor and it will create the command internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the `DataTable` to the `Label` as well:

```vb
Label11.DataBindings.Add("Text", table, "d_salary")
```

Now the `Label` will update automatically when a selection is made.